# Trouble Displaying API Data as Charts using SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, foreach, visualization

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI project where I'm fetching data from an API and aiming to display it as horizontally scrollable BarMark charts. However, I've run into an issue where I'm struggling to correctly integrate the fetched data with SwiftUI's ForEach loop or explore the option of using mirroring. I'm hoping someone could offer some guidance on how to achieve this.

For each financial metric, I have defined an array of key paths representing the metrics. I aim to populate the bar charts with values from the fetched data using these key paths. However, I'm currently encountering issues in integrating the fetched data with the charts and dynamically creating the bars.

How can I effectively populate the bar charts in CashChartsView using the fetched data for the respective metrics?

**This is what I am hoping to achieve.
**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H7yO.png)

This is the code I have written that does not work:

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct CashChartsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StocksViewModel
    var stock: StocksResponse
    
    var financialMetrics: [KeyPath<Cash, Double?>] = [
        \.inventory, \.netIncome, \.debtRepayment,
         \.freeCashFlow, \.dividendsPaid, \.acquisitionsNet,
         \.netChangeInCash, \.accountsPayables,
         \.cashAtEndOfPeriod, \.commonStockIssued, \.deferredIncomeTax, \.operatingCashFlow,
         \.otherNonCashItems, \.capitalExpenditure, \.accountsReceivables, \.otherWorkingCapital,
         \.changeInWorkingCapital, \.commonStockRepurchased, \.purchasesOfInvestments, \.stockBasedCompensation,
         \.cashAtBeginningOfPeriod, \.otherFinancingActivites, \.otherInvestingActivites, \.effectOfForexChangesOnCash,
         \.depreciationAndAmortization, \.salesMaturitiesOfInvestments, \.netCashUsedForInvestingActivites, \.netCashProvidedByOperatingActivities,
         \.investmentsInPropertyPlantAndEquipment, \.netCashUsedProvidedByFinancingActivities
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(financialMetrics, id: \.self) { keyPath in
                    VStack {
                        let metric = keyPath.displayName
                        Text(metric)
                        if let cashData = viewModel.outlook.financialsAnnual?.cash {
                            Chart(data: cashData) { cashEntry in
                                if let value = cashEntry[keyPath: keyPath] {
                                    BarMark(
                                        x: .value(metric, cashEntry.date ?? ""),
                                        y: .value(metric, value)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            Task {
                await viewModel.getOutlook(symbolID: stock.id)
            }
        }
    }
}
    
    extension KeyPath where Root == Cash, Value == Double? {
        var displayName: String {
            switch self {
            case \.inventory: return "Inventory"
            case \.netIncome: return "Net Income"
            case \.debtRepayment: return "Debt Repayment"
            case \.freeCashFlow: return "Free Cash Flow"
            case \.dividendsPaid: return "Dividends Paid"
            case \.acquisitionsNet: return "Acquisitions (Net)"
            case \.netChangeInCash: return "Net Change in Cash"
            case \.accountsPayables: return "Accounts Payables"
            case \.cashAtEndOfPeriod: return "Cash at End of Period"
            case \.commonStockIssued: return "Common Stock Issued"
            case \.deferredIncomeTax: return "Deferred Income Tax"
            case \.operatingCashFlow: return "Operating Cash Flow"
            case \.otherNonCashItems: return "Other Non-Cash Items"
            case \.capitalExpenditure: return "Capital Expenditure"
            case \.accountsReceivables: return "Accounts Receivables"
            case \.otherWorkingCapital: return "Other Working Capital"
            case \.changeInWorkingCapital: return "Change in Working Capital"
            case \.commonStockRepurchased: return "Common Stock Repurchased"
            case \.purchasesOfInvestments: return "Purchases of Investments"
            case \.stockBasedCompensation: return "Stock-Based Compensation"
            case \.cashAtBeginningOfPeriod: return "Cash at Beginning of Period"
            case \.otherFinancingActivites: return "Other Financing Activities"
            case \.otherInvestingActivites: return "Other Investing Activities"
            case \.effectOfForexChangesOnCash: return "Effect of Forex Changes on Cash"
            case \.depreciationAndAmortization: return "Depreciation and Amortization"
            case \.salesMaturitiesOfInvestments: return "Sales/Maturities of Investments"
            case \.netCashUsedForInvestingActivites: return "Net Cash Used for Investing Activities"
            case \.netCashProvidedByOperatingActivities: return "Net Cash Provided by Operating Activities"
            case \.investmentsInPropertyPlantAndEquipment: return "Investments in Property/Plant/Equipment"
            case \.netCashUsedProvidedByFinancingActivities: return "Net Cash Used Provided by Financing Activities"
            default: return ""
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the api response:

```
// MARK: - OutlookResponse

struct OutlookResponse: Codable {
    let rating: Rating?
    let ratios: Ratios?
    let metrics: Metrics?
    let profile: Profile?
    let analysis: Analysis?
    let stockNews: [StockNews]?
    let insideTrades: [InsideTrade]?
    let splitHistory: [SplitHistory]?
    let keyExecutives: [KeyExecutive]?
    let stockDividend: [StockDividend]?
    let financialsAnnual, financialsQuarter: Financials?
}

// MARK: - Financials

struct Financials: Codable {
    let cash: [Cash]?
    let income: [Income]?
    let balance: [Balance]?
}

// MARK: - Cash

struct Cash: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    let date: String?
    let link: String?
    let period, symbol: String?
    let finalLink: String?
    let inventory, netIncome: Double?
    let fillingDate, acceptedDate: String?
    let freeCashFlow, debtRepayment, dividendsPaid, acquisitionsNet: Double?
    let netChangeInCash, accountsPayables: Double?
    let reportedCurrency: String?
    let cashAtEndOfPeriod, commonStockIssued, deferredIncomeTax, operatingCashFlow: Double?
    let otherNonCashItems, capitalExpenditure, accountsReceivables, otherWorkingCapital: Double?
    let changeInWorkingCapital, commonStockRepurchased, purchasesOfInvestments, stockBasedCompensation: Double?
    let cashAtBeginningOfPeriod, otherFinancingActivites, otherInvestingActivites, effectOfForexChangesOnCash: Double?
    let depreciationAndAmortization, salesMaturitiesOfInvestments, netCashUsedForInvestingActivites, netCashProvidedByOperatingActivities: Double?
    let investmentsInPropertyPlantAndEquipment, netCashUsedProvidedByFinancingActivities: Double?
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, each Double should have it's own BarMark chart, the x axios is going to be the dates, the y axios is the double.

Comment: "encountering issues", what are those issues?

Comment: the names of the charts are visible but the charts are not visible

Comment: You need to check each step, is the api call successful, is the received data decoded correctly, does the chart code work as expected (try with mock data).

Comment: i think the problem is in the syntax but i am not sure how to write it, that is why i am asking